# How can I define styles as headings?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In my word document there are some custom heading styles defined. They are based on the existing heading styles which come with Microsoft Word.

[image: sample custom heading properties]

I would like to cross reference these headings throughout my document. While I am aware that I can add anchors to my document I would prefer to directly reference the headings instead of having to add an anchor for each heading. However, they are obviously not recognized by Word as headings because they do not show up in the headings list when selecting a reference target.

How can I tell Word that these are heading styles so that they become available as reference targets?

Answer (score 2):

You can import these defined heading styles and use them as global styles every time you open Microsoft Words. Do the following steps:

- At `Styles` panel, click to `Manage styles`

[image]

- At `Manage styles` windows, click to `Import/Export` button at left-botton corner

[image]

- `Organizer` window is opened, you select your defined styles then click `Copy`. Close window

Now, your customized styles are available throughout all Word documents, you can see them in the `Styles` panel.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. I'm not looking to import these to all Word documents but only want them to be recognized as headings.